# Oracle SQL cursor to replace bulk upload

Tags: sql, oracle, database-cursor

I'm currently collecting a large set of data into an object list as follows:

```
FUNCTION GET_MY_TABLE_CONTENTS
  RETURN MY_TABLE_OBJECT_LIST
AS
v_my_table_list MY_TABLE_OBJECT_LIST;
BEGIN
  SELECT MY_TABLE_OBJECT
  (
  COLUMN_1
  COLUMN_2
  COLUMN_3
  )
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_my_table_list 
  FROM MY_TABLE
  ORDER BY COLUMN_3 desc;

  RETURN v_my_table_list;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END GET_MY_TABLE_CONTENTS;
```

This works fine however because there is so much data it is very slow. I'm trying to change this so that it loads the data in row by row. I think cursors can achieve this but I'm not entirely sure. Can someone please advise on this?

Comment: row-by-row will be even slower. How / where is this function supposed to be used? I think it would be easier to make it return a ref cursor and have the calling code pull data directly from the cursor itself

Comment: I'm using it to collect all of the data from a table. Then via java, use the object list in order to update a front end GUI. So the idea with a cursor is that it would update incrementally rather than the bulk collect. I'm just not sure on the implementation.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by 'update incrementally - are you maybe thinking about [a pipelined function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/pipe_paral_tbl.htm)? A ref cursor might be more suitable though.

Comment: I mean that the records will be obtained one by one, or say in groups of 50 as they are needed by the user. At the minute nothing can happen until the bulk collect finishes and it takes 2 minutes +. I will look into ref cursors

Comment: When you say "all of the data": how many rows would that be?  Loading all of the data from a very large table into a collection for the UI to process would be a very bad idea.

Comment: yup, ref cursors definitely sound like the way to go. It will be as if the Java code had run the query itself, but leaving the cursor definition as a stored proc on the database side.